# How to write all the records from the mysql database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, file

I have this code and when I generate the document it just writes (outputs?) the last row in the database.  I want to obtain all the rows but I do not know how.
What I observe is that I am reassigning the values, but I don't know how to correct this.

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "codeigniter";
    //Establecemos la conexion
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT TimeStrap, Numero, IP, Codigo, Estado, URL, Puerto, ResolucionAccion FROM registros";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Establecemos las variables
            $TimeStap = $row["TimeStrap"];
            $NO = $row["Numero"];
            $IP = $row["IP"];
            $CODIGO = $row["Codigo"];
            $ESTADO = $row["Estado"];
            $URL = $row["URL"];
            $PUERTO = $row["Puerto"];
            $RESOLUCIONACCION = $row["ResolucionAccion"];
        }
    } else {
        echo "No hay resultados";
    }
    //Cerramos la conexion
    $conn->close();

    $sl = "\n";

    //Re-Asignamos variables
    $cont = "$TimeStap $NO  $IP     $CODIGO $ESTADO $URL  $PUERTO   $RESOLUCIONACCION";
    $data = 'TimeStap   NO  IP      CODIGO      ESTADO  URL     PUERTO  RESOLUCION-ACCION'
    .$sl .$cont;

    if ( ! write_file('/var/squid/log/access.log', $data))
    {echo 'No se puede escribir el archivo';}
    else{$success = "El archivo se generó correctamente";}
```

Comment: Alex.  Favor escribís en Ingles cuando usas Stack Overflow.  / Please use English when using Stack Overflow.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: The answer here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php

Comment: Where do you want to write the records? In a file? On screen? The word "escribir" can be translated with different meanings.

Comment: i want to write all of them inside of a .log file

Answer (score 2):

try to put

> Trates de poner

```
$cont = "$TimeStap $NO  $IP     $CODIGO $ESTADO $URL  $PUERTO   $RESOLUCIONACCION";
    $data = 'TimeStap   NO  IP      CODIGO      ESTADO  URL     PUERTO  RESOLUCION-ACCION'
    .$sl .$cont;
```

inside the while and concatenate them, because $data is the variable that is holding your results.

> dentro el `while` y concatenarles, porque `$data` es el variable que contiene sus resulatdos.

```
<?php  $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "codeigniter";
    //Establecemos la conexion
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT TimeStrap, Numero, IP, Codigo, Estado, URL, Puerto, ResolucionAccion FROM registros";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            //Establecemos las variables
            $TimeStap = $row["TimeStrap"];
            $NO = $row["Numero"];
            $IP = $row["IP"];
            $CODIGO = $row["Codigo"];
            $ESTADO = $row["Estado"];
            $URL = $row["URL"];
            $PUERTO = $row["Puerto"];
            $RESOLUCIONACCION = $row["ResolucionAccion"];
            $cont = "$TimeStap $NO  $IP     $CODIGO $ESTADO $URL  $PUERTO   $RESOLUCIONACCION";
            $data = $data.'TimeStap   NO  IP      CODIGO      ESTADO  URL     PUERTO  RESOLUCION-ACCION'
    .$sl .$cont;

        }
    } else {
        echo "No hay resultados";
    }
    //Cerramos la conexion
    $conn->close();

    $sl = "\n";

    //Re-Asignamos variables
    //$cont = "$TimeStap $NO  $IP     $CODIGO $ESTADO $URL  $PUERTO   $RESOLUCIONACCION";
    //$data = 'TimeStap   NO  IP      CODIGO      ESTADO  URL     PUERTO  RESOLUCION-ACCION'
    //.$sl .$cont;

    if ( ! write_file('/var/squid/log/access.log', $data))
    {echo 'No se puede escribir el archivo';}
    else{$success = "El archivo se generó correctamente";}

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php this question is surely a duplicate anyways. Please, write only in english: it's  permitted to add some phrases in other languages in comments, or within the code, but not the question itself. Hay foros en español para eso. Please, take a look to the rules

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT TimeStrap, Numero, IP, Codigo, Estado, URL, Puerto, ResolucionAccion FROM registros";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$regs='';
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Establecemos las variables
        $TimeStap = $row["TimeStrap"];
        $NO = $row["Numero"];
        $IP = $row["IP"];
        $CODIGO = $row["Codigo"];
        $ESTADO = $row["Estado"];
        $URL = $row["URL"];
        $PUERTO = $row["Puerto"];
        $RESOLUCIONACCION = $row["ResolucionAccion"];
        $regs += "$TimeStap $NO  $IP     $CODIGO $ESTADO $URL  $PUERTO   $RESOLUCIONACCION \n"; 
    }
} else {
    echo "No hay resultados";
}
//Cerramos la conexion
$conn->close();


//Concatenamos variables
$encabezado = "TimeStap   NO  IP      CODIGO      ESTADO  URL     PUERTO  RESOLUCION-ACCION \n";
$data = $encabezado.$regs;


if ( ! write_file('/var/squid/log/access.log', $data))
{echo 'No se puede escribir el archivo';}
else{$success = "El archivo se generó correctamente";}
```